# support generation of interface files before calling rosidl_generate_interface

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to generate some .action files using a custom command in my cmake file, and then generate the ROS2 interfaces from these .action files.
I have defined a custom_command / custom_target for the generation, that works, but I could not find a way to force the call of this command before running the rosidl_generate_interfaces macro ; however, this macro first checks for file existence, and then fails...
Any hint?
Thanks,
Charles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361337/support-generation-of-interface-files-before-calling-rosidl_generate_interface/) by [CharlesOnera](https://answers.ros.org/users/22407/charlesonera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The implementation of `rosidl_generate_interfaces()` expects all passed files to exist at configuration time. So you need to make sure that the files you want to generate are generated at configure time rather than as part of a target at build time.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CharlesOnera](https://answers.ros.org/users/22407/charlesonera/) on 2020-09-11**:
Thanks. I replaced the add_custom_command with execute_process in the cmake file and it works!